Dividing by sums in TikZ coords
I want to input mathematically calculated coordinates, containing terms which are divided by sums, into TikZ.
For instance, I would like to use something with a similar syntax to this: \def \cmd {1/(1+1)}
and then input its result into TikZ using syntax similar to this: \coordinate (P) at (0,\cmd);
The reason for my asking is because I'm using the \def command within a \foreach loop, where the value of the defined command changes for each value of the \foreach loop.
Here's a MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \myFraction {3/(2+1)}
\fill[red] (0,0) circle [radius=\myFraction]; % Works!
%\fill[green] (3,\myFraction) circle [radius=1]; % Does not work. :(
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

It is important that the "2+1" structure of the fraction is maintained.

Use curly braces: {\myFraction}

Use braces around \myFraction:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \myFraction {3/(2+1)}
\fill[red] (0,0) circle [radius=\myFraction]; % Works!
\fill[green] (3,{\myFraction}) circle [radius=1]; % Does not work. :(
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Alternately, you can define \myFraction with the additional braces
\def \myFraction {{3/(2+1)}}

and then use \myFraction (without braces)
\fill[green] (3,\myFraction) circle [radius=1];


I would use declare function to define constant(s) and calculate variable(s). A modern view considers all constants, parameters, variables, functions as just variables. The code is a bit cleaner.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={a=-2;b=a+4;}]
\def\myFraction{3/(2+1)}
\fill[red] (0,0) circle(\myFraction); 
\fill[green] (3,{\myFraction}) circle(1); 
\fill[blue] (3,a) circle(1); 
\fill[magenta] (7,a+1) circle(b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

PS: I like the old syntax circle(2) more than the new syntax circle[rađius=2cm].
